# Data not displaying in EditText fields ( Android using php and json for mysql db )

Tags: android, json

EDIT: edited to make the question clearer

The app I created Can display all data in a class using listview. When I click one of the results, EditEmpresaActivity is called but no data is displayed in the EditText fields.

EditEmpresaActivity class which should handle the displaying of the data

```
package com.example.androidhivetest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class EditEmpresaActivity extends Activity {

    EditText txtMarca;
    EditText txtInvestimento;
    EditText txtMarcaTotal;
    Button btnSave;
    Button btnDelete;

    String eid;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // single product url
    private static final String url_product_details = "http://192.168.1.90/android_connect/get_product_details.php";

    // url to update product
    private static final String url_update_product = "http://192.168.1.90/android_connect/update_product.php";

    // url to delete product
    private static final String url_delete_product = "http://192.168.1.90/android_connect/delete_product.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";
    private static final String TAG_EID = "eid";
    private static final String TAG_MARCA = "marca";
    private static final String TAG_INVESTIMENTO = "investimento";
    private static final String TAG_MARCATOTAL = "marcatotal";

    String sMarca, sInvestimento, sMarcaTotal; // edit1

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_empresa);

        // save button
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

        // getting product details from intent
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // getting product id (eid) from intent
        eid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_EID);

        // Getting complete product details in background thread
        new GetEmpresaDetails().execute();

        // save button click event
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // starting background task to update product
                new SaveEmpresaDetails().execute();
            }
        });

        // Delete button click event
        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // deleting product in background thread
                new DeleteEmpresa().execute();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
     * */
    class GetEmpresaDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditEmpresaActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading empresa details. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Getting product details in background thread
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // updating UI from Background Thread
            Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            //runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Check for success tag
                    int success;
                    try {
                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("eid", eid));

                        // getting product details by making HTTP request
                        // Note that product details url will use GET request
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest( url_product_details, "GET", params);

                        // check your log for json response
                        Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                        // json success tag
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            // successfully received product details
                            JSONArray productObj = json
                                    .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                            // get first product object from JSON Array
                            JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                            // product with this eid found
                            // Edit Text
                            txtMarca = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputMarca);
                            txtInvestimento = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputInvestimento);
                            txtMarcaTotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputMarcaTotal);

                            // display product data in EditText
                            txtMarca.setText(product.getString(TAG_MARCA));
                            txtInvestimento.setText(product.getString(TAG_INVESTIMENTO));
                            txtMarcaTotal.setText(product.getString(TAG_MARCATOTAL));

                        }else{
                            // product with eid not found
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to  Save product Details
     * */
    class SaveEmpresaDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditEmpresaActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Saving empresa ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Saving empresa
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // getting updated data from EditTexts
            String marca = txtMarca.getText().toString();
            String investimento = txtInvestimento.getText().toString();
            String marcatotal = txtMarcaTotal.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_EID, eid));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_MARCA, marca));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_INVESTIMENTO, investimento));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_MARCATOTAL, marcatotal));

            // sending modified data through http request
            // Notice that update product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_product,
                    "POST", params);

            // check json success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully updated
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    // send result code 100 to notify about product update
                    setResult(100, i);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to update product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once empresa uupdated
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    /*****************************************************************
     * Background Async Task to Delete Empresa
     * */
    class DeleteEmpresa extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditEmpresaActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Deleting Empresa...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Deleting product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("eid", eid));

                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        url_delete_product, "POST", params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Delete Empresa", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    // product successfully deleted
                    // notify previous activity by sending code 100
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    // send result code 100 to notify about product deletion
                    setResult(100, i);
                    finish();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }
}
```

JSONParser class:

```
package com.example.androidhivetest;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
// return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Comment: Your question and description are pretty vague.

Comment: I'm still looking for the listview. Am I going blind?

Comment: Shouldn't you be extending a ListActivity or ExpandableListActivity?

Comment: Just want to point out that you are running your entire `doInBackground` logic on the UI thread making the whole AsyncTask pointless.

Comment: So the problem is that I am not updating the UI in onPostExectute thus not displaying the data, correct?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you are running the thread

Comment: Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString()); -> this should display a single product in the log cat, but it doesn't. If I make the call in my browser, the JSON query displays correctly!

Comment: I have tried many other things including moving the UI to onPostExecute but my problem is that I am not receiving any response from JSON on logcat when I click on a single product on my list

Comment: Solved by not using a specific query to display details and instead pass the values from ALL results activity to the details activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by not using a specific query to display details and instead pass the values from ALL results activity to the details activity

Answer (score -1):

check your PHP file.i think the json node name not defined properly.